# Choose the lookup column from a combobox in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have the fallowing scenario.

I have a simple form like this:
**Number 1 in the appended image.**

And I have a combobox in it, that display data in two columns. When I start typing text, the combobox makes a search of the content like this:
**Number 2 in the appended image.**

It fills data from the first column, like this:
**Number 3 in the appended image.**

Is there a way I can tell MS Access in wich column I want to search by text I am typing? I want this behavior to happen fromt the data of the second column.

[Images for the post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXBz6.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS Access 2010 Multi column Combobox Autocomplete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981463/ms-access-2010-multi-column-combobox-autocomplete)

Comment: As suggested in the issue linked above, just hide the field you do not want to search or move it after the one you want to search on.

Answer (score 1):

you can get the data from the second column by using

ComboBoxName.Column(1) in a vba code.

try inserting the following in the combobox after update event

msgbox me.combobo(1)